# A static array implementation in C++

Tags: c++, array, memory-management

I'm implementing a basic array data structure with basic functionalities.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "barray.h"

BArray::BArray(int init_size)
{
    b_array = new int[init_size]();
    array_size = init_size;
}

BArray::BArray(int init_size, int init_val)
{
    b_array = new int[init_size];
    array_size = init_size;

    for(int i = 0; i < init_size; ++i)
        b_array[i] = init_val;
}

BArray::BArray(const BArray & rhs)
{
    array_size = rhs.array_size;
    b_array = new int[array_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
        b_array[i] = rhs[i];
}

BArray::~BArray()
{
    delete [] b_array;
}

int BArray::getSize() const
{
    return array_size;
}

int BArray::operator[](int index) const
{
    return *(b_array + index);
}

int& BArray::operator[](int index)
{
    return *(b_array + index);
}

BArray& BArray::operator=(const BArray& rhs)
{
    if(this == &rhs)
        return *this;

    array_size = rhs.array_size;

    delete [] b_array;

    b_array = new int[array_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
        b_array[i] = rhs[i];

    return *this;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const BArray& arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.array_size; ++i)
        out << arr[i] << " ";

    return out;
}
```

And the header file

```
#ifndef BARRAY_H
#define BARRAY_H

class BArray
{
public:
    BArray() = delete;                    //Declare the default constructor as deleted to avoid
                                          //declaring an array without specifying its size.
    BArray(const int init_size);
    BArray(int init_size, int init_val);  //Constructor that initializes the array with init_val.
    BArray(const BArray & rhs);           //Copy constructor.
    ~BArray();                            //Destructor.


    int operator[](int index) const;      //[] operator overloading for "reading" index value.
    int& operator[](int index);           //[] operator overloading for "setting" index value.
    BArray& operator=(const BArray& rhs); //Copy assignment operator.

    //Utility functions.
    int getSize() const;

    //Friend functions.
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const BArray& arr);

private:
    int* b_array;
    int array_size;
};



#endif // BARRAY_H
```

Can you please give me a feedback on what is missing, what is wrong and what is good? 
I mean in terms of memory allocation, operators overloading, etc...

Is this is the best way this class can be implemented?

Edit:
This is how I tested the code

```
#include <iostream>

#include "barray.h"

int main()
{

    //BArray invalid_instance; //Default constructor is deleted.

    BArray barr(5); //Declaring an array of size 5, this initializes all values to zeros.

    std::cout << barr[2] << std::endl;

    barr[2] = 15;   //Setting index 2 to 15.

    std::cout << barr[2] << std::endl; //Reading out value of index 2.

    BArray anotherArray(barr); //Copy constructor.

    std::cout << anotherArray[2] << std::endl;

    anotherArray[3] = 8;

    BArray assignArray = anotherArray; //Copy assignment operator.

    std::cout << assignArray[2] << std::endl;

    std::cout << assignArray; //Printing out array values.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some test code that you add to the question to show us how the class is used?

Comment: Yes sure. I will add it now.

Comment: How's that a "static" array?

Comment: @L.F. By static I mean not dynamic/resizeable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The default-ctor won't be implicitly declared as there are user-declared ctors.
2. When you can define a default-ctor with reasonable behavior, consider doing so.
   If you use in-class initializers to `0` resp. `nullptr` for the members, it can even be explicitly defaulted, making the class trivially default-constructible.
3. Top-level `const` on arguments in a function declaration is just useless clutter.
4. Consider investing in move-semantics to avoid costly copies.
5. If the allocation in one of the ctors throws, your dtor will be called on indeterminate members, which is **undefined behavior**.
   Use mem-initialisers or pre-init `b_array` to `nullptr` to fix it.
6. Your copy-assignment also has pathological behavior in the face of exceptions. That aside, it pessimises the common case in favor of self-assignment. Read up on the copy-and-swap idiom. As a bonus, you get an efficient `swap()` out of it.
7. Using a `std::unique_ptr` for the member would allow you to significantly simplify the memory-handling.
8. Keep to the common interface-conventions. Failure to follow it makes generic code nigh impossible. Specifically, `.getSize()` should be `.size()`.
9. You are missing most of the expected interface, specifically iterators (normal, constant, reverse, related typedefs, `.data()`).
10. Better names for the private members would be `array` and `count`.

Answer (score 4):

I would allow the default constructor and make it default to a 0 size array. with the optimization that b_array is a `nullptr`.

Then you can also add move constructors/assignment. Where the moved-from object gets a `b_array = nullptr;`

On of the basic functionalities of a container is iteration. So you should add a `begin()` and `end()` that return the `b_array` and `b_array+array_size` resp. Don't forget the const versions.